# SQL Select statements - more than one output column

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say I got a query like this:

```
select count(*) as Morning from Table 
where timestamp between '01.08.13 06:00:00' AND '01.08.13 10:00:00'
```

Now I would like to have an output for noon and evenings. Yes I could do three queries, but is it possible to create a select statement which returns all three (morning, noon, evening) ?

Comment: You've tagged this for both Oracle and MySQL.  Which database are you actually using?  The syntax is likely to differ between the two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select sum(case when timestamp between '01.08.13 06:00:00' 
                                   and '01.08.13 10:00:00'
                then 1 
                else 0 
           end) as Morning,
       sum(case when timestamp between '01.08.13 10:00:00' 
                                   and '01.08.13 14:00:00'
                then 1 
                else 0 
           end) as Noon,
       sum(case when timestamp between '01.08.13 14:00:00'
                                   and '01.08.13 18:00:00'
                then 1 
                else 0
           end) as Evening
from Table
```

Comment: but will sum() return the count here? just trying to understand if count() is better?

Comment: @skv for count you'll need do `COUNT(IF(timestamp between '01.08.13 06:00:00' AND '01.08.13 10:00:00', 1, NULL))` - it's just more complicated. `SUM` will do the trick easier.

Comment: The inner statement in the `sum()` will return `1` if `true`. The sum function will sum up the cases when true.

Comment: @juergend This is true for MySQL, But is it true also for Oracle? (the question is tagged with both)

Comment: @MahmoudGamal - This syntax won't work in Oracle.  You'd need a `CASE` inside the `SUM` to translate the boolean to a number.  Oracle does not have a `boolean` data type in the SQL language (there is a PL/SQL boolean).

Comment: thank you very much :) the statement seems good.
but for some reason i get an ORA-00907 Error - missing right parenthesis :/

Comment: @user2428207: So are you using MySQL or Oracle and why did you tag your question with both?

Comment: ah... that was not my intention... sry

Comment: @user2428207: In Orcale you need a `case` statement. I updated my answer.